# Pytorch, cant' run CNN on GPU. Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm building a simple image recognition convolutional neural network and trying to run this on my GPU but I haven't done something important apparently.

I checked If GPU is available at the beginning and in train, set batches to the device (cuda:0).

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim


# Checks if GPU is available otherwise uses CPU
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda:0")
    print("Running on the GPU!")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    print("Running on the CPU!")


REBUILD_DATA = False

# Data clean up and format
class DogsVsCats():
    IMG_SIZE = 50
    CATS = "PetImages/Cat"
    DOGS = "PetImages/Dog"

    LABELS = {CATS: 0, DOGS: 1}

    training_data = []

    catcount =  0
    dogcount = 0

    def make_training_data(self):
        for label in self.LABELS:
            print(label)
            for f in tqdm(os.listdir(label)):
                try:
                    path = os.path.join(label, f)
                    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
                    img = cv2.resize(img, (self.IMG_SIZE, self.IMG_SIZE))

                    self.training_data.append([np.array(img), np.eye(2)[self.LABELS[label]] ])

                    if label == self.CATS:
                        self.catcount += 1
                    elif label == self.DOGS:
                        self.dogcount += 1
                except Exception as e:
                    pass

        np.random.shuffle(self.training_data)
        np.save("training_data.npy", self.training_data)

        print("Cats: ", self.catcount)          
        print("Dogs: ", self.dogcount)


if REBUILD_DATA:
    dogsvcats = DogsVsCats()
    dogsvcats.make_training_data()


training_data = np.load("training_data.npy", allow_pickle=True)

# print(len("training_data.npy"))

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5)

        x = torch.randn(50,50).view(-1,1,50,50)

        self._to_linear = None
        self.convs(x)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self._to_linear, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 2)

    def convs(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2,2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2,2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), (2,2))

        print(x[0].shape)

        if self._to_linear is None:
            self._to_linear = x[0].shape[0]*x[0].shape[1]*x[0].shape[2]
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.convs(x)
        x = x.view(-1, self._to_linear)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.softmax(x, dim = 1)

net = Net().to(device)

optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
loss_function =  nn.MSELoss()

X = torch.Tensor([i[0] for i in training_data]).view(-1, 50, 50)
X = X/255.0
y = torch.Tensor([i[1] for i in training_data])


VAL_PCT = 0.1
val_size = int(len(X)*VAL_PCT)

print(val_size)

train_X = X[:-val_size]
train_y = y[:-val_size]

test_X = X[-val_size:]
test_y = y[-val_size:]


BATCH_SIZE = 100

EPOCHS = 1

def train(net):
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        for i in tqdm(range(0, len(train_X), BATCH_SIZE)):
            # print(i, i+BATCH_SIZE)
            batch_X = train_X[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].view(-1,1,50,50).to(device)
            batch_y = train_y[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].to(device)

            net.zero_grad()

            outputs = net(batch_X)
            loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        print(loss)

correct = 0
total = 0

with torch.no_grad():
    for i in tqdm(range(len(test_X))):
        real_class = torch.argmax(test_y[i])
        net_out = net(test_X[i].view(-1, 1, 50, 50))[0]
        predicted_class = torch.argmax(net_out)
        if predicted_class == real_class:
            correct += 1
        total += 1

print("Accuracy: ", round(correct/total,3))



train(net)
```

Sorry if it's too simple of a question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: when you pass the tensors into your training u need to .cuda them. The batches of training data, if u print them u will see cpu,u need to change it to gpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post the line number of the error, but I'm thinking its from this snipit:

```
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i in tqdm(range(len(test_X))):
            real_class = torch.argmax(test_y[i])
            net_out = net(test_X[i].view(-1, 1, 50, 50))[0]
            predicted_class = torch.argmax(net_out)
            if predicted_class == real_class:
                correct += 1
            total += 1
```

You have to put the input to your `net` must be put to the device, so maybe change the line

```
     net_out = net(test_X[i].view(-1, 1, 50, 50))[0]
```

to

```
     net_out = net(test_X[i].view(-1, 1, 50, 50).to(device)[0]
```